# C++ Code for Screen Capturing

Tags: c++

I need to write code which will do screen sharing like WebEx or Team Viewer for Windows PC. The requirement is I **don't have admin access** and I **can not Install** any application or software for this. I know below technology but none of them is working for me. I have tried all sample for this code project URL  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5051/Various-methods-for-capturing-the-screen

(1) GetDC(NULL) and BitBlt with SRCCOPY <= This will not capture **Transparent Window** and It cause **GDI hung** (Just try drawing in Paint.. your pencil stuck for some time when BitBlt operation performerd)

(2) GetDC(NULL) and BitBlt with SRCCOPY and CAPTUREBLT Option <= This will **hide Cursor** when I call BitBlt Operation and also **GDI Hung** when BitBlt Operation Performed.

(3) I also tried with **DirectX** using GetFrontBufferData.. This cause **Flicker** of my Transparent Window.

(4) I tried with **Windows Media API** but this require **Windows Media Encoder** to be Installed.

(5) I tried with **Mirror Driver** also but this require Driver to be Installed with Admin Access.

Can any one please suggest API where without any Installation I can capture entire screen and No flicker or GDI hung problem.

Thanks in Advance.....

Comment: If you happen to have the `Qt` libraries already in your machine, you can get the screenshot with them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that whatever method you'll use you have to hook into the system (intercept some OS-to-driver call) to let the system give you the time to do your operation safely. that requires whatever software to run in administrative mode.

All the above methods fail because of some internall call failure due to not enough priviledges.

If you think a bit, if running an exe at user level can share a system call even from non system level users, the system may have serious security breaches: I just have to deliver an application you use that shares your screen without you notice that.

So, instead to try to fool your company security policies, just ask to your admins: if you need those software for business purpose, they will do what is needed.

Comment: Hi Emilio, Could you please advise what software I need to Install and after Installation how to grab screen with out any Issue ? Could you please guide more with complete solution. If I need to ask admin to Install any software I will ask admin. Please help....

Comment: Unless you are the very first person that have to do a virtual meeting with others (so you are a IT developer, and you should be local admin yourself), you should not ask them for a specific software, but explain them what your problem is. The company must already have a standard for that. If it doesn't, arrange a meeting between you, your and their boss and explain what the issue is about. It's not just a matter of "I want that here", but "I want to do this why...". Ask you colleagues before asking to strangers

Comment: ... by the way, you cited Webex and Teamviewer. I can cite Ms Linc...  Youcan even have the good old neetmeeting already on the pc (look in the windows folder)... The are all silimar in the "sharing" capabilities, but makes no sense choosing them youself alone (the first guy having a videophone never did a video call!)